# How do I modify a k-ary heap's C code so that the layout of a 4-heap fit on a cache line and the array is padded to cache-align the heap

Tags: c, caching, heap

In Anthony LaMarca and Richard Ladner's January 6 1997 paper titled "The Influence of Caches on the Performance of Heaps", published in the *ACM Journal of Experimental Algorithmics* they write that:

> In our heapsort executions, all three of the cache-aligned heaps
>   outperform the traditional heap and the majority of the speedup occurs
>   in the remove-min operation. As before, we see that increasing fanout
>   from 2 to 4 provides a large performance gain.

This finding is important because as memory access times grow larger relative to processor cycle times, the cache performance of algorithms has an increasingly large impact on overall performance.

I'm uncertain, however, how to actually implement cache alignment.  I would therefore like to know how to modify the 4-ary heap implementation at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-ary-heap/ so that four elements fit in a cache line, and the array is padded to cache-align the heap?

Comment: I show here how  to  allocate 256-byte aligned data for the k-ary heap.

// allocate 256-byte aligned data


element *array = (element *)aligned_alloc(256, ARR_SIZE * sizeof(element));

Comment: Although allocating on a cache-aligned boundary is certainly helpful, you might find that a [B-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-heap) will give you better performance. See the original article, [You're Doing It Wrong](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1814327) for more detailed explanation. You'll have to do a bit of searching to find an implementation.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, I commend you for your excellent answer and comment.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, Why does the B-Heap perform better than the binary heap in terms of faster memory access times? Thanks.

Comment: The first two sentences of the Wikipedia article say why. I suggest you read it. Then, for a complete discussion, read the other article I linked. I pointed you at the answer. Don't expect me to spoon-feed it to you. In short, the B-Heap optimizes the heap layout to prevent excessive virtual memory page accesses; it's more cache-friendly. But don't take my word for it. Read the linked article so you understand why that's the case.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, I read the linked article. But how does the B-heap provide the desired cache alignment? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: It appears that the author left the implementation up to the reader. He hints at how it's done, but doesn't provide concrete examples. Searching for a readable implementation wasn't particularly fruitful, and I haven't taken the time to puzzle one out. In any case, closer reading of the article indicates that the B-Heap is most effective in the case of large heaps where there's considerable virtual memory pressure. It might be a net loss if your heap fits completely in memory.